# Starting a vueJS app with PM2 starts an empty process instead

Tags: vue.js, deployment, pm2

```
pm2 start npm -- serve
pm2 start npm --watch -- run dev
pm2 start npm --name "vue-app" -- start
sudo pm2 start npm run serve --name vue-app -- start
```

When I run those it will start a process but not my app because when I do `sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN` I don't see the 8080 port being used, either that or I get "script not found".

Here is my package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "vue-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
}
```

Since at least one of those commands have to be correct, do I have to modify my package.json file?

Comment: Why do you use PM2 for a Vue app? You're paying a server for nothing, an SPA is static. You could host it on Netlify/Vercel for free.

Comment: So I could just build it and host it on S3 for exemple? Would that make connection to the backend api more difficult?

Comment: S3 is not a good place for an app, it's more for assets since it's quite slow AFAIK. But you can host [it there](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/host-static-website/) if you really want to host on AWS. More difficult to connect to the backend? Not really, pretty much the same: target an URL. You could micro-optimize it on the same provider with kubernetes and all, but this is probably out of the scope here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did to make it work was cd into the root folder of the frontend and run this command:

`pm2 serve dist 8080 --spa`

But as kissu mentioned I'll need to move it to a different host since it's a static app, amplify or netlify for exemple.

Comment: Clearly, will be cheaper/easier/more powerful.

Answer (score 0):

S3 is not a good place for an app, it's more for assets since it's quite slow AFAIK. But you can host [it there](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/host-static-website/) if you really want to host on AWS.
More difficult to connect to the backend? Not really, pretty much the same: target an URL.
You could micro-optimize it on the same provider with kubernetes and all, but this is probably out of the scope here.